# Embarcadero Delphi XE8 under 64 bit Windows 8.1

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

The result of compiling my project using Delphi XE8 under 64 bit Windows 8.1 is 64 bit executable OK.

Is it possible to set Delphi XE8 up to compiles 32 bit executable, because it will be used under Windows XP 32 bit computer?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ah, removed that comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The result of compiling my project using Delphi XE8 under 64 bit Windows 8.1 is 64 bit executable OK.

Only if you specifically opt to compile a 64 bit executable.

> Is it possible to set Delphi XE8 up to compiles 32 bit executable, because it will be used under Windows XP 32 bit computer?

Yes it it possible to target 32 bit executables. Since Delphi XE2, two Delphi compilers for Windows have been supplied, a 32 bit compiler and a 64 bit compiler. It's entirely up to you which one you choose. You can perfectly well compile 32 and 64 bit applications even though you run the compiler on a 64 bit operating system.

This is all controlled by the project settings. In the Project Manager there is a node named *Target Platform*. Select Win32 for a 32 bit Windows program, or Win64 for a 64 bit Windows program. By default, new projects are only configured with settings for Win32. You have to explicitly add a new target platform to enable Win64.

You should spend some time familiarising yourself with this area, starting with this documentation topic: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Activating_and_Configuring_the_Target_Platform

Now, you specifically mentioned XP 32 bit. That target is no longer supported by Delphi. What that means in practise is that Embarcadero no longer tests on XP. The latest versions of Delphi can still produce executables that execute correctly on XP, but there is a danger that you might call API functions that don't exist on XP. So, there is a strong need for you to test your executable file on XP, if you wish to continue supporting XP.

Comment: Thank You, I read that Target Platform (Win32), so now I expect executable to be 32 bit. But yesterday I did copy the executable into a Oracle VirtualBox - Windows XP and did try to run there - it raised some exception and did not started, so I decided that executable is 64 bit. Now I will do the same, to see what will be the exception.

Comment: The exception raised again : **SO2015.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience**. The executable did not run at all.

Comment: I just answered the question that you asked about 32/64 bit targets. If you want help on why your app won't run you'll need to ask a new question. Make sure you include a [mcve] when you do that.